# ¿Es posible visualizar un " print 'Mensaje' " que existe dentro de un Store Procedure y mostrarlo en un metodo o alguna clase que lo capture en c#?

Tags: c#, stored-procedure, clase, print, store

```
create proc Proceso
as
begin

print 'Inicia Proceso'

--Realizo proceso 1, este proceso puede tardar algun tiempo determinado

print 'Proceso 1 Realizado'

--Realizo proceso 2,

print 'Proceso 2 Realizado'

SELECT * FROM Orden

--Muestra Data

print 'Fin del proceso'

end
```

Comment: Te faltó el código en C# donde intentas usar eso. [edit] la pregunta es el camino

Comment: Creo que no, lo que sí es posible es retornar una variable como Output, mira: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59737854/3613462 + https://stackoverflow.com/q/11260418/3613462 + https://stackoverflow.com/q/20227122/3613462 Saludos.